# How built in functions like theme_field() are called in drupal?

Tags: 7, theming

I have function theme_field() in my `field.module`. But I don't know how it's getting called. I have searched entire drupal project for the function calling statement . But I couldn’t find it. How this function is getting invoked? Please advice.

```
function theme_field($variables) {
//    print_r($variables);
  $output = '';

  // Render the label, if it's not hidden.
  if (!$variables['label_hidden']) {
    $output .= '<div class="field-label"' . $variables['title_attributes'] . '>' . $variables['label'] . ':&nbsp;</div>';
  }

  // Render the items.
  $output .= '<div class="field-items"' . $variables['content_attributes'] . '>';
  foreach ($variables['items'] as $delta => $item) {
    $classes = 'field-item ' . ($delta % 2 ? 'odd' : 'even');
    $output .= '<div class="' . $classes . '"' . $variables['item_attributes'][$delta] . '>' . drupal_render($item) . '</div>';
  }
  $output .= '</div>';

  // Render the top-level DIV.
  $output = '<div class="' . $variables['classes'] . '"' . $variables['attributes'] . '>' . $output . '</div>';

  return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consult [hook_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7).

It is called via [theme()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme/7) which can be called directly or indirectly on a [render array](https://www.drupal.org/node/930760)

Each module that introduces a theme element will define a base implementation (what you are looking at in your question) for theme and other modules can override it if they wish.

Look at field.default.inc in Field module, line 212:

```
$info = array(
          '#theme' => 'field',
          '#weight' => $display['weight'],
          '#title' => $instance['label'],
          '#access' => field_access('view', $field, $entity_type, $entity),
          '#label_display' => $display['label'],
          '#view_mode' => $view_mode,
          '#language' => $langcode,
          '#field_name' => $field['field_name'],
          '#field_type' => $field['type'],
          '#field_translatable' => $field['translatable'],
          '#entity_type' => $entity_type,
          '#bundle' => $bundle,
          '#object' => $entity,
          '#items' => $items,
          '#formatter' => $display['type']
        );
```

Theme will then go through this process below to determine whether to render via template file or theme function (screenshot from page 82 of Drupal 7 Module Development).

[image]